# Web Scraping using AWS Lambda and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-scraping, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to scrape data off a website every 15 minutes using lambda and storing it in a table using dynamoDB for a timeseries cost analysis. The code works, but dynamoDB has a read limit capacity, and I cannot seem to retrieve data post 2240 rows to store it as CSV. Is there another way to continue storing the 15 mins data for free? Do you think storing the dynamoDB data over a s3 bucket and deleting old data entries from the dynamo table would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no read limit blocking your requests. You're simply not paginating. DynamoDB [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) and [`Scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) will only return 1MB per request. To fetch the rest, you will need to paginate.

> DynamoDB paginates the results from Query operations. With pagination, the Query results are divided into "pages" of data that are 1 MB in size (or less). An application can process the first page of results, then the second page, and so on.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html